# How to deploy changes in AOSP to target without rebooting target

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, adb, android-source

I am working on android 4.4.2 source for cubieboard 4.
When I am making any changes in source, I follow below procedure:

```
mmm {PATH_TO_CHANGED_FOLDER_WITH_ANDROID.MK}  
adb shell  
mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs /system  
chmod 777 system  
exit  
ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=out/target/product/kylin-cubieboard4 adb sync  
adb reboot
```

Here for example when I am making changes in camera application camera.kylin.so file is updated and pushed using sync. But changes are not reflected when I start camera app. **I need to do `adb reboot` to get changes reflected.**

I even tried `adb install -r` or

```
adb shell stop  
adb shell start
```

But that didn't help! And problem with reboot is again I need to set permissions before syncing changes to android system.

Any suggestions to achieve this without rebooting to save development time?

Comment: Do you know in which process this library is used? If it's the `mediaserver` process then perhaps you could try killing it, because it should then be restarted automatically IIRC.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Yes its mediaserver process. Killing it did the Job!

Comment: @Michael how to find out which process the library is using? for example audio.primary.gmin.so

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187799/how-to-get-list-of-all-processes-accessing-a-shared-library try this method